# Redis with rails. You need to reconnect to Redis after forking error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I am using Redis with my Rails app. I have sidekiq gem installed too.  My redis server runs in the same machine in default port.

I created a initializer which initalizes a redis lient.

config/initializers/redis.rb

```
$redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)
```

I have another initalizer that sets the number of accounts currently active in the system.

config/initializers/z_account_list.rb

```
$redis.set('accounts',Account.count);
```

In one of my views i am using this piece of code.

```
<div class="more-text">and <%= "#{$redis.get('accounts')}" %> more...</div>
```

When i set the value for accounts manually in redis without using the initializer, everything works fine. But when i add the initializer, i get

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Tried to use a connection from a child process without reconnecting. You need to reconnect to Redis after forking.):
```

I searched for the error. But most solutions are for resque and has something to do with after_fork.  Since i am new to Rails and Redis and since i am not using Resque i am getting a little confused.  Please help me out on this.

Comment: What ruby web server are you using? Unicorn or other web servers that `fork` child processes of a master process will need to be configured to reconnect Redis, and likely any other database/socket/etc connection your app uses after forking. The unicorn docs, or whatever server you are using, will have info on how to configure what is done before/after fork. Should be as simple as reconnecting in the config's `after_fork` block.

Comment: I am using pushion passenger web server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In forked environments like pushion passenger, we have to reconnect to redis whenever a worker is forked.  My biggest confusion was where to put the reconnection statements.  In many blogs it was suggested to put it in config/environments.rb.  But it didn't work for me.

I added

```
if defined?(PhusionPassenger)
  PhusionPassenger.on_event(:starting_worker_process) do |forked|
    if forked
      $redis.client.disconnect
      $redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)
      Rails.logger.info "Reconnecting to redis"
    else
      # We're in conservative spawning mode. We don't need to do anything.
    end
  end
end
```

to config/initializers/redis.rb
and everything started working fine.

Comment: So we can now just call `$redis.client.ensure_connected` instead of disconnecting and then making a connection?

Comment: You don't need to do anything, Redis will reconnect automatically if it detects that the connection was forked. http://sorentwo.com/2015/08/25/managing-redis-reconnections-from-ruby.html

Comment: @ParkerSelbert I use memcached for cache, redis with resque, what should I do? I'm using puma here is my worker boot 
`Redis.current = Redis.new(url: ENV['REDIS_URL'], size: redis_size)
    $redis = Redis.current` 

`if defined?(Resque)
    Resque.redis = $redis
  end`
And nothing to reconnect to memcached/rails cache, do I need to? how?

Comment: @StarWars For Redis you're better off using `Redis.current` everywhere, instead of `$redis`. The `current` value will return the a healthy connection, where the `$redis` global can get out of sync. I'm not sure how memcached/dalli handle automatic reconnects though, sorry.